# Custom move accessory for UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Is it possible to use a custom view as the move accessory that appears on the right hand side of the `UITableViewCell` when a `UITableView` is in editing mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  UIKit has no support for this, and attempting to override it is risky and likely to break with future versions of iOS.  This is strongly recommended against.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible without using some sort of private API. What you could do is modify your accessoryView while the tableview is in edit mode, but I don't think you can change the view that the user "grabs onto."

Could you provide an example of what you're trying to accomplish? Maybe there's something else that can get you the functionality you're looking for.